# Where are all the emails stored in postfix?

Tags: email, xubuntu, postfix

I am a newbie in linux.
Recently, I have installed postfix MTA in xubuntu. I just want to know where are all the emails stored in my postfix server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

"The short answer is that the mailboxes are
either in /var/mail or in /var/spool/mail; the long answer is that it
depends on your Postfix configuration."

Direct quote from [here](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Uk/uk.comp.sys.mac/2008-02/msg01208.html).